# Variable not reachable without exception

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I have a very weird problem, the classic of works on localhost and not in server.

I've tried to find a bigger problem and discovered that this code :

```
 <div class="pageHeader"><h1>Products2   #{products.debug}  </h1></div>
```

When :

```
@ManagedBean(name="products")
@SessionScoped
public class ProductsBean {
private String debug = "Debug : ";

public ProductsBean() {
    debug = "Debug : ";
}
public String getDebug() {
    return debug;
}

public void setDebug(String debug) {
    this.debug = debug;
}
```

And the `debug` string has getters/setters,

Works perfectly in localhost but not on remote. In the remote server it doesn't echo the string at all, and no exception gets thrown and I have no idea how to start looking for the problem. The thing is that this problem gets repeated in other ways, for instance this page has a dataTable which appears empty, though it's not in localhost. when I tried file uploading in an whole different page I got exception of `Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null`, which is not the problem in this case, but it seems to be related somehow I guess

Any help? I'm running on Oracle Linux Server with Oracle GlassFish

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What server are you deploying this on? Do you see any exceptions in server logs? Are you able to access other properties for your ProductsBean class?

Comment: I'm running on Oracle Linux Server with Oracle GlassFish. and I mentioned that no exception gets thrown. and it seems as if I can't access other properties on the class no

Comment: You mentioned you get an exception of "Target unreachable, identifier resolved to null" on file upload. Can you paste the stack trace for this? I understand this is not a direct problem, but could be related.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'loadSimCards' resolved to null
```

I believe `#loadSimCards` resolved to null during processing.
The object is not getting created/prepopulated in your bean.

Check the code and verify if it is indeed getting populated.
You can post your Java code if you are still facing issues.

Also check beans.xml file and declaration in faces-config.xml

Reference - [JEE CDI tip: Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2010/03/05/jee-cdi-tip-target-unreachable-identifier-resolved-to-null/)

Comment: It does, but it's not the issue i get the same problem across my app, i think it has something to do with CDI.

Comment: I'm not declaring in faces-config.xml. I've tried instead of using `@ManagedBean` to use the `@Named`, since I saw that in other beans that work that was the method that used, and stil same result.

Answer (score -1):

The first step in my mind would be to do a Right Click -> View Source in the browser and let us know what it shows.  In the view source if the string "#{products.debug} is not getting printed, it means that the server is indeed evaluating the EL Expression, but at the time of rendering it is coming as an empty string.

- Can you please provide the actual getters/setters.
- Can you put loggers/SOPs in them and let us know whether they are being called and in what sequence.
- Replace the pure EL Expression with a data-binding control like h:inputText and see what happens.

  < h:inputText value="#{products.debug}" />
- Probably unrelated, but do you have a < base /> tag declared in your page in the head section? Base tag href provides the location from which child resources are loaded.  I have seen some abnormal behavior in the past while shifting servers, when the main page is loaded from from the remote while the child resources are loaded from the localhost itself on your developer box, because one forgets to change the base tag reference.

Comment: Please remember that in localhost this works perfectly, getters & setters are basic, auto generated, but i'll add them nonetheless